# $(this).attr("id").slice(-1) is working but $(this).id.slice(-1) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5.3

I have appended a button to the blade as a variable and the properties of that button are as follows

```
 var $btnDelete = $('<input />',{

                'id': 'btn_delete'+ x,
                'type':'button',
                'name':'btn_delete'+ x,
                'class':'btn btn-danger editor_remove  editor_remove_leave_types ',          
                'onclick':'RemoveUpdateLeaveTypes(this)',
                'data-id':x  });
```

Note: x is just a variable(0,1,2 etc.)

This is how the button is append to a div of id="xx2" :-

```
 $('#xx2').append($btnDelete);
```

Here, is the above mentioned JavaScript function of that button:

```
function RemoveUpdateLeaveTypes(el)
```

{

```
    var currentId=$(el).id.slice(-1);
    console.log('currentId '+currentId);
```

}

After clicking on this button this error message will appear on the console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined
at RemoveUpdateLeaveTypes (leavePolicyDetails.js:944)
at HTMLInputElement.onclick (leave-policies:1)
```

but ,if I use this command i will have no errors

```
var currentId=$(el).attr("id").slice(-1);
```

Please explain me the conflict in here ,thanks in advance..

Comment: Please update the question with a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button).

Answer (score 5):

There is no `id` property for the jQuery object (`$(el)` is a jQuery object). To get DOM element property either use jQuery [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)(or [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)) method or get DOM object by index and get the property.

```
var currentId = $(el).prop('id').slice(-1);
// or
var currentId = $(el)[0].id.slice(-1);
// or you can get DOM object using get() method
var currentId = $(el).get(0).id.slice(-1);
```

---

**UPDATE :** Since you are passing the DOM object as an argument and you can get id property directly from it so there is no need to wrap it using jQuery.

```
// el === $(el)[0]
var currentId = el.id.slice(-1);
```

Comment: but what is the difference in using just `$(el).id.slice(-1)` and the    working one `$(el).attr("id").slice(-1)` ? plz explain me the reason.

Comment: @Kalanka : `attr()` is also one of the jQuery method used to retrieve attribute value

Answer (score 1):

You are passing in the dom element itself as `this` in the html so just get the id property of that element without jQuery which does nothing to help for this situation

```
var currentId= el.id.slice(-1);
console.log('currentId '+currentId);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = ["apple", "windows", "ubuntu", "cola", "system"];

var answer = function (ele){
    if (ele.charAt(0) == "a" || ele.slice(-1)== "a")
    return ele
}

console.log(input.filter(answer))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value